# Error when saving an HDF5 file on a Julia server using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http, julia, hdf5, writefile

I'm using JavaScript to select an HDF5 file on the client-side and send it to a Julia server. The Julia server is supposed to save the file and then read data from it. The read data should then be sent back to the web application.

However, I'm encountering an error when trying to save the file on the server. Despite the error, the file is actually being saved correctly.

Furthermore, I have also ruled out any issues with returning the data to the web application, as everything works fine when I exclude the write_h5 function and only read an existing file. This suggests that the problem lies specifically with the write_h5 function or the process of saving the HDF5 file on the server.

I hope i presented my problem clearly.
Thank you in advance for your assistance and support in resolving my issue.

```
Activating project at `~/julia`
[ Info: Listening on: 127.0.0.1:8081, thread id: 1
┌ Error: handle_connection handler error
│   exception =
│    IOError: write: broken pipe (EPIPE)
│    Stacktrace:
│      [1] uv_write(s::Sockets.TCPSocket, p::Ptr{UInt8}, n::UInt64)
│        @ Base ./stream.jl:1064
│      [2] unsafe_write(s::Sockets.TCPSocket, p::Ptr{UInt8}, n::UInt64)
│        @ Base ./stream.jl:1118
│      [3] unsafe_write
│        @ ~/.julia/packages/HTTP/NVWp3/src/Connections.jl:122 [inlined]
│      [4] write
│        @ ./strings/io.jl:244 [inlined]
│      [5] write
│        @ ./io.jl:674 [inlined]
│      [6] unsafe_write(http::HTTP.Streams.Stream{HTTP.Messages.Request, HTTP.Connections.Connection{Sockets.TCPSocket}}, p::Ptr{UInt8}, n::UInt64)
│        @ HTTP.Streams ~/.julia/packages/HTTP/NVWp3/src/Streams.jl:95
│      [7] write
│        @ ./strings/io.jl:244 [inlined]
│      [8] write(io::HTTP.Streams.Stream{HTTP.Messages.Request, HTTP.Connections.Connection{Sockets.TCPSocket}}, s::Base.CodeUnits{UInt8, String})
│        @ Base ./strings/basic.jl:758
│      [9] (::HTTP.Handlers.var"#1#2"{typeof(handle_requests)})(stream::HTTP.Streams.Stream{HTTP.Messages.Request, HTTP.Connections.Connection{Sockets.TCPSocket}})
│        @ HTTP.Handlers ~/.julia/packages/HTTP/NVWp3/src/Handlers.jl:61
│     [10] #invokelatest#2
│        @ ./essentials.jl:729 [inlined]
│     [11] invokelatest
│        @ ./essentials.jl:726 [inlined]
│     [12] handle_connection(f::Function, c::HTTP.Connections.Connection{Sockets.TCPSocket}, listener::HTTP.Servers.Listener{Nothing, Sockets.TCPServer}, readtimeout::Int64, access_log::Nothing)
│        @ HTTP.Servers ~/.julia/packages/HTTP/NVWp3/src/Servers.jl:447
│     [13] (::HTTP.Servers.var"#16#17"{HTTP.Handlers.var"#1#2"{typeof(handle_requests)}, HTTP.Servers.Listener{Nothing, Sockets.TCPServer}, Set{HTTP.Connections.Connection}, Int64, Nothing, Base.S
```

Julia and package versions:

```
julia> versioninfo()
  Julia Version 1.8.2
  Commit 36034abf260 (2022-09-29 15:21 UTC)
  Platform Info:
    OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0)
    CPU: 8 × Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8279U CPU @ 2.40GHz
    WORD_SIZE: 64
    LIBM: libopenlibm
    LLVM: libLLVM-13.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
    Threads: 1 on 8 virtual cores

(julia) pkg> st
  Status `~/Project.toml`
    [f67ccb44] HDF5 v0.16.14
    [cd3eb016] HTTP v1.8.1
    [682c06a0] JSON v0.21.4
```

My Julia code:

```
using HTTP,HDF5,JSON

function handle_requests(req::HTTP.Request)
    if startswith(req.target, "/process-file")
        return process_file(req)
    end
    return HTTP.Response(404, CORS_RES_HEADERS, "Not found")
end

HTTP.serve(handle_requests, "127.0.0.1", 8081)

dir  = "tmp"

function write_h5(filename,data)
    file = joinpath(dir, "$(filename)")    
    open(file, "w") do fid
         write(fid, data)
    end
end

function read_h5()
    file = readdir(dir,join=true)[1]
    fid  = HDF5.h5open(file, "r")["Data"]
    data = fid["data"] |> read
    d = Dict("data" => data)
    close(fid)
    return d
end

function process_file(req::HTTP.Request)   
    multipart = HTTP.parse_multipart_form(req)
    filename = multipart[1].filename
    filedata =  multipart[1].data |> read 
    write_h5(filename,filedata)
 
    d = read_h5()

    result = Dict(
        "message" => "File saved successfully",
        "data" => d
    )
 
       return HTTP.Response(200, CORS_RES_HEADERS, JSON.json(result))

end
```

My HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="browse-measurements" accept="application/x-hdf,application/x-hdf5"/>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
// Browse on PC
  async function sendFileToServer(file) {
     const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append("file", file);
      
     const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8081/process-file", {
         method: "POST",
         body: formData,
         header: {
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
           "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST"},
     });  
     const result = await response.json();
     console.log("Ergebnis vom Server:", result.message);
  }
  
  document.getElementById("browse-measurements").addEventListener("change", async (event) => {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      if (!file) return;
      await sendFileToServer(file);
  });
```

Comment: It is interesting to note that when I send the data to the Julia server using a POST request and then initiate a GET request with a second button to read the file and send it back to the application, I occasionally receive the same error message in the Julia server's REPL. However, despite the error, the data is successfully received by the application.